# In doppler effect, approaching frequency reaches infinity. What is the physical realization/manifestation of this?

Tags: relativity, doppler-effect

[image]I have used this link where I plugged in the numbers. I am having trouble understanding what does it mean to have a frequency infinity when the velocity of the source matches the velocity of the sound wave. This ties with sonic boom, but I can't wrap my head around the transition from diminishing positive frequency(source is getting closer)-> inifinity(not sure what's going on here) -> negative frequency(source is moving away)

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Sound/dopp.html#c1

Answer (score 1):

The increase in frequency as the sound source moves towards you is due to the subtraction in the denominator of the expression for Source approaching. When you divide by a smaller number, the value increases.  As the source speed approaches the speed of sound, the difference becomes smaller and smaller, and the resulting number is unbounded as the difference approaches zero.

But of course this result is non-physical: sound cannot propagate if the wavelength is less than the average spacing between the particles of the gas, liquid, or solid that is carrying the sound. The frequency and the wavelength are related by (wavelength)*(frequency) = (speed of sound); higher frequencies go with shorter wavelengths.

So there is always a low-pass filter in place, where sounds above a certain frequency are blocked.  Of course you don't want to travel at exactly the speed of sound, for it makes your plane shake.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_barrier

Comment: Can you expand on "low pass filter in place...." part?

Comment: High-pass, band-pass, and low-pass filters are terms taken from electrical engineering.  A low-pass filter is designed to allow the lower frequencies to pass through the filter, while blocking the higher frequencies.  In optics the terms are used with respect to wave lengths, and so the meanings are reversed!   The point is that the discrete nature of matter limits the lowest wavelengths (the highest frequencies) of sound from passing through materials.